# firestore: does not detect collection

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The problem has arisen to me when passing it to the new version of angular 16.2.0, that of my old project is the 16.0.0.0 but when passing it to the most current version is that it does not detect the collection of firestore said collection if it exists here I pass the code:

```
 getObtenerTarea(userUID: string): Observable<Tareas[]> {
    // 1. Obtén la referencia a la colección 'tarea' en Firestore.
    const tareas = collection(this.firestore, 'tarea');
    // y filtra las tareas por el 'userUID' proporcionado.
    const tareasQuery = query(
      tareas,
      orderBy('fecha', 'desc'),
      where('userUID', '==', userUID)
    );
    // 3. Utiliza collectionData para obtener los datos de las tareas
    // y convierte esos datos en objetos 'Tareas'.
    return collectionData(tareasQuery, { idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      // 4. Usa el operador 'map' para transformar los datos de Firestore en objetos 'Tareas'.
      //Este primer map:  map((data: DocumentData[]) transforma los datos de firestore
      //y el segundo map: data.map((item: DocumentData) transforma esos datos de firestore en objetos Tareas
      map((data: DocumentData[]) =>
        data.map((item: DocumentData) => ({
          id: item['id'] as string,
          userUID: item['userUID'] as string,
          descripcion: item['descripcion'] as string,
          realizada: item['realizada'] as boolean,
          en_progreso: item['en_progreso'] as boolean,
          categoria: item['categoria'] as string,
          fecha: new Date(),
        }))
      )
    );
  }
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirestore, getFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { TareasModule } from './tareas/tareas.module';
import { NavBarComponent } from './nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavBarComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    TareasModule,
    FormsModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
  ],
  providers: [AngularFireAuth],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
export const environment = {
  firebase: {
    projectId: 'tareas-66631',
    appId: '1:1009807285977:web:1b4e80d90f664f8304e8c8',
    storageBucket: 'tareas-66631.appspot.com',
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyCM28GGpsN-_W3d-YKWZFXquKzHUCBAwio',
    authDomain: 'tareas-66631.firebaseapp.com',
    messagingSenderId: '1009807285977',
  },
};
```

This error is in firefox:

> ERROR FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore
> FirebaseError index.esm2017.js:949
> Angular 9
> getObtenerTarea tareas.service.ts:29
> obtenerTareas lista-tareas.component.ts:76
> ngOnInit lista-tareas.component.ts:38
> Angular 22
> RxJS 6
> Angular 11

I have tried to solve the error seeing if I was missing the collection in firebase and it is not like that the collection I have it does not tell me that I have coding errors either I have used artificial intelligence to try to solve it and according to the ia it says that it is fine.